Rendering a custom Arabic font in my Flutter
I’m encountering an issue with rendering a custom Arabic font in my Flutter application. The text appears with separated letters rather than correctly joined script, which is essential for proper Arabic typography.
This issue started occurring after I updated Flutter to the latest version. Before the update, the same font rendered perfectly with correctly joined letters.
here extract of my code
Text(
//‘$\_counter’,
‘مرحبا بالعالم’,
//style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: ‘muhammadi’,
fontSize: 20,
//fontFeatures: \[FontFeature.enable(‘liga’)\], // Enable ligatures if needed.
),
textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
),

notice please that i have tested with richtext and textspan, but that doesn’t resolve the problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wLbrINFsHnha1xc13CW3Z2quJZ2vv0pM/view?usp=sharing
i have changed the font with an other and it worked, but i want to work with my font at the last version flutter

testing it with no changes to your code, I ran it with Flutter version (Channel stable, 3.27.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.26100.2605], I get the result in this image ... is the text script in my image also not appearing correctly? (asking am I getting the same result as yours?)
